# Using IntelliMouse in Parallels 5

Tags: mouse, parallels, intellimouse

I'm running Windows 7 in Parallels 5 and have a five button USB mouse (Microsoft IntelliMouse).

I have my mouse's side buttons mapped to the Forward and Back (browser) commands.  However, Parallel's Mouse Synchronization Service seems to be intercepting the mouse keypress event for these two buttons, and remapping them to the Windows Start Menu command.

Any way to undo this?  That is, get my Back/Forward buttons working again?

Comment: Does Win7 recognize the mouse correctly? Most virtualization software uses its own drivers in the guest system for mouse synchronization.

Comment: Win7 doesn't recognize it, that's the issue.  i.e. Parallels is using its own driver / mouse synchronization service -- but in doing so, is losing the back/forward functionality.  So I guess my question is, can I configure this in-between service to do what I want?  Or is what I'm seeking impossible?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

How about mapping the mouse to ALT + LEFT and ALT + RIGHt for going back and forward in the browse instead?